# How to keep my server online?

Tags: c#, sockets

My C# program has a server. It starts like this:

```
serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
serverSocket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
serverSocket.Listen(10);
serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);
```

OnAccept:

```
private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
            try
            {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);
                clientSocket.BeginReceive(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None,
                    new AsyncCallback(OnReceive), clientSocket);
                AddLog("підключення", "Спроба нового підключення");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AddLog("підключення", "ПОМИЛКА нового підключення. " + ex.Message);
            }
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);
}
```

And it works perfect... until after some time i find it being offline. Sometimes i see the situation when new clients cant connect, but old clients which connected earlier are still connected. It happens not any often, so its hard to find out what are the reasons.

How do i make sure my server is always online whenever the app is running and my internet is online?

I have some thoughts, but i would like to know what is a right way to do it.

Comment: Do you remember to close the sockets when you are done with them?  It is possible clients are dropping off but at some point you have exhausted all the file descriptors for the process and no new connections can be accepted.

Comment: I guess youve just explained why new clients cant connect sometimes. Thank you. But is there any way to check from the program whether my server is online or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call BeginAccept again within OnAccept so that it can start accepting new connections again. Also I would advise against using Socket and would use TcpListener instead which is a higher level API.

Something like this should work:

```
private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
{
   bool beginAcceptCalled = false;
   try
   {
       //start the listener again
       _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(OnAccept, null);
       beginAcceptCalled = true;
       Socket socket = _listener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);
       socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveTimeout, 15 * 60 * 1000);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Logger.Error(string.Empty, ex);
       if (!beginAcceptCalled)
       {
          //try listening to connections again
          _listener.BeginAcceptSocket(OnAccept, null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Can Gencer, i do use "BeginAccept" in "OnAccept". Without it i would probably be stuck with only one client. What advantages will i get from using "TcpListener"?

Comment: Could it be that you get an exception in your OnAccept so it never gets called again? TcpListener doesn't have any specific advantages except it has a higher level  and simpler API and should be safer to use in that aspect.

Comment: ReceiveTimeout = 50. Or thats too small? I didnt set "SendTimeout" cause my server doesnt send anything first, only responds to clients.

Comment: @Can Gencer, i would doubt that such an exception is possible, cause i use "try". Very likely, Duck is right, i didnt close my clientsockets, just disconnected them. But i cant say for sure, cause checking takes days. Would you recommend some way to check(from my program) if my server is "connectable"? So program could check it time to time and take some actions if needed.

Comment: @Alena You can write a small program using TcpClient to periodically open a connection to your server. If the connection part succeeds then that means that the server is listening. Is it possible you post your OnAccept code as well?

Comment: that looks ok.. one thing you can do is use "netstat -an" on the command line to show all the active connections on the server computer. That way you can see if a lot of sockets are being left open. Are you sure you are disconnecting the sockets? You don't need to close them if you disconnect, it already closes them.

Comment: Another program doesnt seem too good to me, i had an idea of downloading something like this http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ through WebClient, but then i thought that therere more appropriate ways. I mean, servers like MySQL or Apachi never get down even after an Itnernet reconnection, so they must use some way of checking.